# How can I delete a just-typed newline character in bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, shell

I sometimes copy-paste paths into the terminal, and often accidentally copy the newline character. For example, I want to find then read the contents of `foobar.txt`.

```
$ locate foobar.txt
/home/sparhawk/Document Directory/foobar.txt
```

I then select the second line with a triple click. (Oops, it selects the trailing newline too!) Since there is a space in the path, I need to enclose the path in quote marks. Hence type in

```
$ cat '
```

and middle-click to paste. This produces

```
$ cat '/home/sparhawk/Document Directory/foobar.txt
>
```

since I have inserted a newline before closing the `'`. At this point, I cannot press backspace to delete the newline. Is there a way to delete this just-typed newline?

### More information

At this point I can either `SIGINT` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, or complete the quote with another `'`. Let's say I do the latter.

```
$ cat '/home/sparhawk/Document Directory/foobar.txt
> '
cat: /home/sparhawk/Document Directory/foobar.txt
: No such file or directory
```

which makes sense, as I just typed in a path with  newline in it. However, at this point, I can press the up arrow, to load the last command. i.e.

```
$ cat '/home/sparhawk/Document Directory/foobar.txt
'
```

At this point, I *can* press backspace twice to delete the newline. (N.B. there is no `>` in the second from-history example.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bash uses [GNU Readline Library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) for command-line input and editing. Unfortunately this library processes the input only line by line. The [`readline()`](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC24) call returns after finishing the line by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Next line (after showing the `$PS2` "`>`" prompt) is processed by a separate `readline()` call.

When you go back in the editing history to a multi-line input Readline treats the input as a single "line" with newlines (the `$PS2` prompts are not displayed) so you can edit the whole multi-line input as you described.

I use the following trick to solve the problem you presented: When I have input with unwanted newline I cancel it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Then I return to the cancelled input by pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>). Then I can remove the newline by <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and do other edits.

Input with unwanted newline at the end, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:

```
$ cat 'xyz
> ^C
```

After pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> the input returns event without the trailing newline:

```
$ cat 'xyz
```

Comment: Yeah, I had come across that workaround too. It's probably the cleanest way to overcome this. +1 for references, and showing that a workaround is the only solution.